# EmberJS: How to update Ember CLI based apps

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Angular has https://update.angular.io/ that guides with the proper way to update (along with dependencies et al.). Likewise, is there a way to know how to update an Ember app properly?

Obviously, changing the version of the `ember` package in `bower.json` and doing an `bower install && npm install` doesn't seem to be the ideal way.

Comment: You can copy paste your title into google and you will get results for [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update) and every ember-cli release comes with [upgrade notes](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases)

Comment: So the proper way to update the app is to check which version of the Ember CLI updates Ember (the `ember` package) to the version I need, and then do `ember-cli-update --to the.cli.version.that.comes.with.the.ember.version.i.need`, right?

Comment: @karthikaruna Have you had a look at the link in my answer? Was it helpful ?

Answer (score 2):

Detailed update information are included in release notes provided for ember-cli on GitHub: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/

For projects that aren't using a very old version, the workflow is mostly this one:

1. Update globally installed ember-cli to latest stable release
2. Update globally installed ember-cli-update to latest stable release
3. Clean up your project by deleting `tmp`, `dist` and `node_modules` folders.
4. Run `ember-cli-update` to update project to match current blueprint.
5. Run `ember-cli-update --run-codemods` to update project to match current best practices.

Before [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update) has become the official tool for updating projects, running `ember init` again after updating projects `ember-cli` dependency manually was the officially recommended workflow. [ember-cli@3.2.0](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v3.2.0) was the last release for which this workflow was recommended. But ember-cli-update should support all versions for which a tag exists in [ember-new-output repo](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/tags), which should be true for all stable releases of ember-cli.

You could of course update your dependencies individually and not follow the recommended configuration provided by ember-cli. But be aware that uncommon combination may not work as stable as you are used to.

If your app still uses Ember App Kit, which has been deprecated in 2014, you could find a migration guide in [their readme](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit). But you should consider carefully if rewriting wouldn't be quicker than updating such an outdated app.

Comment: So the proper way to update the app is to check which version of the Ember CLI updates Ember (the `ember` package) to the version I need, and then do `ember-cli-update --to the.cli.version.that.comes.with.the.ember.version.i.need`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete step-by-step guide for upgrading an ember here,

https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/upgrading/